# Scrolling ListView mixes images

Tags: android, scroll, textview, imageview, simplecursoradapter

I've implemented a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` in order to insert images and text into my `ListView`, however the images move around when the user scrolls. How can I get them to stay in place? Here is my code (I stripped it down for simplicity):

```
 final class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public mySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cur,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
   super(context, layout, cur, from, to);
   mContext = context;
   mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
 }

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return v;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

        ImageView bar11 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        ImageView bar12 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar2);
           ImageView bar13 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar3);
        TextView sign = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text3);                        
               sign.setText(currency);

            if (someValue == 0){
                bar11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

          if (someValue == 1){
                bar12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }        

          if (someValue == 2){
                bar13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }   

   }
 }
```

*row.xml*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/bar"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="65dp"

  android:background="@drawable/greenbar"/>

    <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/bar2"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="65dp"

  android:background="@drawable/two"/>

    <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/bar3"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="65dp"

  android:background="@drawable/two"/>


 <TextView

  android:id="@+id/text3"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

  android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

*List.xml*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/expense"
android:background="@drawable/expensebackgroundblue">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contentlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your check should look like this `if (someValue == 0){
                bar11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{ bar11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}` due to view recycling

Comment: Well I actually have 3 images which would mean I'd need to have at least two "if's" so that's where I run into problems...I should've specified that earlier

Comment: Could you paste your xmls here?

Comment: No problem, I added them above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is happening because of view recycle what you need to do to set the views visibility to visible or gone like this

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    ImageView bar11 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar);
    ImageView bar12 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar2);
       ImageView bar13 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar3);
    TextView sign = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text3);                        
           sign.setText(currency);

        if (someValue == 0){
            bar11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else
        {
            bar11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (someValue == 1){
            bar12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        {
            bar12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }        

      if (someValue == 2){
            bar13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        {
             bar13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```